# grouping on status change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have sample like below and i want to group the data on data change.

```
My table:
id  Status  time
1   a      20/6/2015 8:00
2   a      20/6/2015 8:46
3   a      20/6/2015 9:00
4   b      20/6/2015 9:00
5   b      20/6/2015 9:16
6   a      20/6/2015 9:17
7   a      21/6/2015 9:20
```

Sample output:

```
Status  mintime          maxtime
a      20/6/2015 8:00   20/6/2015 9:00
b      20/6/2015 9:00   20/6/2015 9:16
a      20/6/2015 9:17   21/6/2015 9:20
```

Basically i want to group the data on status ,taking min and max time of data only if status change.

My problem, if i use grouping on status column then i will get as below 
Status  mintime maxtime

```
a   20/6/2015 8:00  21/6/2015 9:20
b   20/6/2015 9:00  20/6/2015 9:16
```

I don't want the output like above which returns me 2 data.I want to group the data based on status change.

Comment: Grouping *while preserving order of rows* is pretty tricky. Can you expand on why this is useful to see if there's perhaps another way to get the job done?

Comment: Can you please explain ,how to get this done with any other method?

Comment: If I knew what you needed, as opposed to how you think it would best be solved, I or someone else might. (See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))

Comment: Yes, i just want the method to solve the problem not a solution for me question.

Comment: As of now, i can think of using cursor, check for the status change process in the temp table and show it to the application. But i want to know is there any other method which can be optiminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the different-of-row number method.  The difference of `row_number()` -- with particular arguments -- identifies groups.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select status, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by time) -
              row_number() over (partition by status order by time)
             ) as grp
      from mytable t
     ) t
group by status, grp;
```