# Grouping Data by Changing Status Over Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to assign a group number to distinct groups of rows in a dataset that has changing data over time.   The changing fields are tran_seq, prog_id, deg-id, cur_id, and enroll_status in my example.  When any of those fields are different from the previous row, I need a new grouping number.  When the fields are the same as the prior row, then the grouping number should stay the same. When I try ROW_NUMBER(),  RANK(), or DENSE_RANK(), I get increasing values for the same group (e.g. the first 2 rows in example).  I feel I need to ORDER BY start_date as it is temporal data.

```
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+
|    | tran_seq | prog_id | deg_id | cur_id | enroll_status | start_date |  end_date  | desired |
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+
| 1  |    1     |   6     |   9    |   3    |     ENRL      | 2004-08-22 | 2004-12-11 |    1    |
| 2  |    1     |   6     |   9    |   3    |     ENRL      | 2006-01-10 | 2006-05-06 |    1    |
| 3  |    1     |   6     |   9    |   59   |     ENRL      | 2006-08-29 | 2006-12-16 |    2    |
| 4  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2014-01-21 | 2014-05-16 |    3    |
| 5  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2014-08-18 | 2014-12-05 |    3    |
| 6  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAP      | 2015-01-20 | 2015-05-15 |    4    |
| 7  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2015-08-25 | 2015-12-11 |    5    |
| 8  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAP      | 2016-01-12 | 2016-05-06 |    6    |
| 9  |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2016-05-16 | 2016-08-05 |    7    |
| 10 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAJ      | 2016-08-23 | 2016-12-02 |    8    |
| 11 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2017-01-18 | 2017-05-05 |    9    |
| 12 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2018-01-17 | 2018-05-11 |    9    |
+----+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+
```

Once I have grouping numbers, I think I can group by those to get what I'm ultimately after: a timeline of different statuses with start dates and end dates.  For the example data above, that would be:

```
+---+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
|   | tran_seq | prog_id | deg_id | cur_id | enroll_status | start_date |  end_date  |
+---+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
| 1 |    1     |   6     |   9    |   3    |     ENRL      | 2004-08-22 | 2006-05-06 |
| 2 |    1     |   6     |   9    |   59   |     ENRL      | 2004-08-29 | 2006-12-16 |
| 3 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2014-01-21 | 2014-12-05 |
| 4 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAP      | 2015-01-20 | 2015-05-15 |
| 5 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2015-08-25 | 2015-12-11 |
| 6 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAP      | 2016-01-12 | 2016-05-06 |
| 7 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2016-05-16 | 2016-08-05 |
| 8 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     LOAJ      | 2016-08-23 | 2016-12-02 |
| 9 |    2     |   12    |   23   |   45   |     ENRL      | 2017-01-17 | 2018-05-06 |
+---+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using PARTITION BY in ROW_NUMBER() ?

Comment: @FLICKER  That would return the exact opposite of what the OP is looking for

Comment: @FLICKER Yes.  I created a column using: [grp] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tran_seq, prog_id, deg_id, cur_id, enroll_status ORDER BY start_date).  The problem is that it assigns different numbers to the first 2 rows instead of the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic XY problem, in that you are asking for an intermediate step to a different solution, rather than asking about the solution itself.

As you included your overall end goal as a bit of an addendum however, here is how you can reach that without your intermediate step:

```
declare @t table(tran_seq int, prog_id int, deg_id int, cur_id int, enroll_status varchar(4), start_date date, end_date  date, desired int)
insert into @t values
 (1,6,9,3   ,'ENRL','2004-08-22','2004-12-11',1)
,(1,6,9,3   ,'ENRL','2006-01-10','2006-05-06',1)
,(1,6,9,59  ,'ENRL','2006-08-29','2006-12-16',2)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2014-01-21','2014-05-16',3)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2014-08-18','2014-12-05',3)
,(2,12,23,45,'LOAP','2015-01-20','2015-05-15',4)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2015-08-25','2015-12-11',5)
,(2,12,23,45,'LOAP','2016-01-12','2016-05-06',6)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2016-05-16','2016-08-05',7)
,(2,12,23,45,'LOAJ','2016-08-23','2016-12-02',8)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2017-01-18','2017-05-05',9)
,(2,12,23,45,'ENRL','2018-01-17','2018-05-11',9)
;

select tran_seq
      ,prog_id
      ,deg_id
      ,cur_id
      ,enroll_status
      ,min(start_date) as start_date
      ,max(end_date) as end_date
from(select *
           ,row_number() over (order by end_date) - row_number() over (partition by tran_seq,prog_id,deg_id,cur_id,enroll_status order by end_date) as grp
     from @t
    ) AS g
group by tran_seq
        ,prog_id
        ,deg_id
        ,cur_id
        ,enroll_status
        ,grp
order by start_date;
```

### Output

```
+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
| tran_seq | prog_id | deg_id | cur_id | enroll_status | start_date |  end_date  |
+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
|        1 |       6 |      9 |      3 | ENRL          | 2004-08-22 | 2006-05-06 |
|        1 |       6 |      9 |     59 | ENRL          | 2006-08-29 | 2006-12-16 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | ENRL          | 2014-01-21 | 2014-12-05 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | LOAP          | 2015-01-20 | 2015-05-15 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | ENRL          | 2015-08-25 | 2015-12-11 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | LOAP          | 2016-01-12 | 2016-05-06 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | ENRL          | 2016-05-16 | 2016-08-05 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | LOAJ          | 2016-08-23 | 2016-12-02 |
|        2 |      12 |     23 |     45 | ENRL          | 2017-01-18 | 2018-05-11 |
+----------+---------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: @iamdave Thank you very much for your answer.  I knew the outer query and asked my question because I was having issues with the subquery part.  I saw Gordon Linoff's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814089/grouping-on-status-change and used that to filter my larger dataset down to this one.  ROW_NUMBER() - DENSERANK() is great, thanks!